# Condition for an additive function to be continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

The problem below is Problem 7 from this year's Miklos Schweitzer competition (contest ended Nov 4th).

> Suppose that $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is an additive function (that is $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x, y \in \Bbb{R}$) for which $x \mapsto f(x)f(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ is bounded of some nonempty subinterval of $(0,1)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

I attempted a solution by contradiction, but didn't got very far. I was thinking to exploit the fact that a discontinuous additive function is unbounded on every interval and its graph is dense in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 5):

First observe that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist rational numbers $p,q > 0$ with $p<\epsilon$ and $p^2 + q^2 = 1$. This is just a consequence of well-known formulas for construction of Pythagorean triples. E.g., we can choose 
$$
 p = \frac{2n+1}{n^2 + (n+1)^2} \quad \text{ and } q = \frac{2n(n+1)}{n^2 + (n+1)^2}
$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large. For such pairs we define an associated rotation matrix
$$
A_p = \begin{bmatrix} q & p \\ -p & q
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The assumption in the problem means that the function
$$
F(x,y) = f(x) f(y)
$$
is bounded on some arc $I$ of the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Now if $(x,y)$ is arbitrary and $A_p$ is a rational rotation matrix as above, then (identifying the matrix and the induced linear map)
\begin{align*}
F(A_p(x,y)) &= F(qx + py, -px + qy) = f(qx+py) f(-px+qy) \\
 &= (qf(x)+ pf(y)) (-pf(x) + qf(y)) \\
 &= qp(f(y)^2 - f(x)^2) + (q^2 - p^2) f(x)f(y),
\end{align*}
where we used the (easily proved) fact that $f$ is linear over the rational numbers.

Now we fix a small subarc $J$ of $I$, and a rational rotation matrix $A_p$ with $p>0$ such that $A_p(J) \subset I$. (This is possible because by the argument in the first paragraph we can find $A_p$ arbitrarily close to the identity.) For $(x,y) \in J$ the above calculation then implies that
$$
 f(y)^2 - f(x)^2 = \frac{F(A_p(x,y))}{qp} - \frac{(q^2 - p^2) F(x,y)}{qp}
$$
so that $f(y)^2 - f(x)^2$ is bounded on $J$. Since $f(x)f(y)$ is also bounded on $J$, it follows that $(f(y)+if(x))^2 = f(y)^2 - f(x)^2 + 2i f(x)f(y)$ is bounded on $J$, so that $f$ is bounded on the projections of $J$ to both coordinate axes. As stated in the question, local boundedness of $f$ implies continuity.

Comment: You say that $F$ is additive in each variable. How do you deduce that $F(Q)-F(R)=F(Q-R)$? This seems to work only if $QR$ is parallel to one of the coordinate axes.

Comment: I missed that when I wrote it, I'll see if the proof can be fixed.

Comment: There is another error in the proof. You cannot extend directly the boundedness from one subinterval to the whole $(0,1)$. if $(x,y)$ is on the arc where the circle is bounded and $p\neq q$ are two rational such that $(px,qy)$ is also on the unit circle then you can find explicitly $x$ and $y$ in terms of $p,q$ and it turns out that $x^2$ and $y^2$ are both rationals, which excludes most of the remaining points... Anyway, the idea to go into 2 dimensions is interesting, and it might lead to something towards the solution.

Comment: OK, I think I fixed the proof by replacing it by a completely new one. Still has the idea of going into 2 dimension and using Pythagorean triples, but hopefully this time without all the mistakes...

Comment: Nice proof. I see no error.  The key is realizing that you can bound $f(x)^2-f(y)^2$ and realizing this means $f(x)$ is bounded, but I especially like how you conclude $f(x)$ is bounded from the fact that $f(x)^2-f(y)^2$ and $f(x)f(y)$ are bounded.  I wouldn't have thought of that approach, since it uses complex numbers and everything in the problem is real. By taking a very short trip into the complex plane, we quickly deduce a non-trivial fact. Not a difficult step, but very short and sweet, I think.